# How to get the number of path components of the set of roots of a polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, reference-request, big-list

Sorry in advance for the open ended question. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a polynomial. What techniques are there for obtaining the number of path components of $f^{-1}(0)$ from the coefficients of the polynomial of $f$ ?

In the probem I am considering, $f$ is quadratic (If that helps)

Comment: The quadratic case should definitely be more doable then the general case since all real quadratic polynomials can be diagonalized.

Comment: @GregMartin Can you elaborate on that ? I know all symmetric bilinear forms can be diagonalized

Comment: @GregMartin I don't see how this strategy will work since we will need the similtaneous diagonalization of symmetric bilinear forms (if we assume our polynomial is homogenous)

Comment: A quadratic form in many variables can be diagonalized all in one go—precisely because a quadratic form can be written using a symmetric bilinear form $x^TAy$ (the quadratic form is then $x^TAx$).

Comment: @GregMartin But each projection of $f$ wil give a different bilinear form, how do you diagonalize all these similtaneously ? Am I missing something here ?